# Why does the same value get written 5 times to the array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

```js
var flagArray = [];
var flagTarget = document.getElementById("content");

var flag = {
  init: function(country) {
    if (country) {
      this.country = country;
      flagArray.push(Object.create(flag));
    }
  },
  draw: function() {
    var pos = flagArray.indexOf(this.country);
    if (this.country === "norway") {
      flagArray[pos] = '<div class="flag ' + this.country + '"><div class="part1"></div><div class="part2"></div><div class="part3"></div><div class="part4"></div></div>';
    } else {
      flagArray[pos] = '<div class="flag ' + this.country + '"><div class="part1"></div><div class="part2"></div></div>';
    }
    flagTarget.innerHTML += flagArray[pos];
  },
};

flag.init("ivorycoast");
flag.init("sweden");
flag.init("denmark");
flag.init("finland");
flag.init("norway");

flagArray.forEach(function(flag) {
  flag.draw();
});
```

I've been struggling with this school assignment for too many hours now. Why does the last flag.init value get written 5 times to the array?

Comment: The `this.country = country;` in the `init()` method always references the prototype object and not the instance. afterwards you add 5 instances, which all use the same prototype object and hence `country` property, which later on gets used in `draw()` to do the output.

Comment: You mean instead of each value you just get `norway` 5 times?

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes/ch2.md) is a good explaination of how `this` works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't, but it *seems* like it does.

What's happening is that you're updating `country` on `flag` five times, and each time you're creating a new object that inherits from `flag` and pushing that on the array. So the end result is five different objects in the array, all of which inherit from `flag`, and none of which have their own `country` value. So the `country` you see on them is the one inherited from `flag`, which is the last value you assigned to `this.country`.

If you want them to inherit from `flag` but each have their *own* `country` value, you need to remember the object created with `Object.create` and set `country` on *it*:

```
init: function(country) {
  if (country) {
    var newFlag = Object.create(flag);
    flagArray.push(newFlag);
    newFlag.country = country;
  }
},
```

(There's a more advanced way I show after the following diagrams.)

Side note: There's a separate problem in `draw`, this line:

```
var pos = flagArray.indexOf(this.country);
```

should just be

```
var pos = flagArray.indexOf(this);
```

Because the array contains objects, not country strings. That said, you don't need to use `flagArray` in `draw` at all.

Let's throw some ASCII-Art (actually, Unicode-art) at your current code to understand what you're seeing:

You start out with this in memory:

```
                                                         +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
flag−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−>|       (object)        |
                                                         +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                                                         | init: (function)      |
                                                         | draw: (function)      |
                                                         +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+

             +−−−−−−−−−−−+
flagArray−−−>|  (array)  |
             +−−−−−−−−−−−+
             | length: 0 |
             +−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

Then after the first `init` call, you have:

```
                                                         +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
flag−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+−−−−−−>|       (object)        |
                                                 |       +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                                                 |       | init: (function)      |
                                                 |       | draw: (function)      |
                                                 |       | country: "ivorycoast" |
                                                 |       +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                                                 |
             +−−−−−−−−−−−+                       |
flagArray−−−>|  (array)  |                       |
             +−−−−−−−−−−−+                       |
             | length: 1 |    +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+  |
             | 0         |−−−>|    (object)   |  |
             +−−−−−−−−−−−+    +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+  |
                              | [[Prototype]] |−−+
                              +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

You've created a new object with `flag` as its prototype, and set `flag`'s `country` to `"ivorycoast"`.

After the second call to `init`, you have:

```
                                                         +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
flag−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+−+−−−−>|       (object)        |
                                                 | |     +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                                                 | |     | init: (function)      |
                                                 | |     | draw: (function)      |
                                                 | |     | country: "sweden"     |
                                                 | |     +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                                                 | |
             +−−−−−−−−−−−+                       | |
flagArray−−−>|  (array)  |                       | |
             +−−−−−−−−−−−+                       | |
             | length: 2 |    +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+  | |
             | 0         |−−−>|    (object)   |  | |
             | 1         |−+  +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+  | |
             +−−−−−−−−−−−+ |  | [[Prototype]] |−−+ |
                           |  +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+    |
                           |                       |
                           |   +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+   |
                           +−−>|    (object)   |   |
                               +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+   |
                               | [[Prototype]] |−−−+
                               +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

...and so on, until `flagArray` is filled with five separate objects, all using `flag` as their prototype, and `flag` has `"norway"` for its `country` property.

---

Here's that more advanced way to add `country` that I mentioned. If I were writing production code, I wouldn't use it for this (too verbose), but just for completeness: There's a second argument you can give `Object.create` that can have a list of properties to add to the new object. You specify the properties by giving their name and an *object* the specifies the various aspects of the property, like whether it's enumerable, whether it's read-only or writable, its initial value (or a getter and/or setter), etc. The `writable`, `enumerable`, and `configurable` features of a property are all defaulted `false` when you do this, but they default `true` when you create a property by just assigning to it. So to do the same thing we're doing with `newFlag.country = country`, we have to specify all those things and say `true` to make the property the same.

So, this does the same thing the version earlier using `newFlag` did, just without the temporary variable:

```
init: function(country) {
  if (country) {
    flagArray.push(Object.create(flag, {
        country: {
            enumerable: true,
            configurable: true,
            writable: true,
            value: country
        }
    }));
  }
},
```

Comment: Precise explanation!

Comment: Thanks, great explanation!

Comment: @AnttiKeränen: No worries. I just noticed this line in `draw`: `var pos = flagArray.indexOf(this.country);` You shouldn't have `.country` there, the array contains objects, not country strings. I've updated the answer. (But you don't really need to use `flagArray` in `draw` at all.)

Comment: I did something similar to your second answer:                 this.country = country;
                flagArray.push(Object.create(flag, {
                    "country": {"value": country}

Comment: @AnttiKeränen: Yup, that works, just note the thing about how that makes the property on the object non-enumerable and read-only.

Answer (score 1):

Using `Object.create(flag)` you set the `flag` as prototype of each element in the array. The prototype is shared between all objects, so `this.country` gets updated on the prototype object in each `init` call and inherited by every element in the array.

To create a separate object you should try `Object.assign`, for example:

`flagArray.push(Object.assign(Object.create(flag), { country : country }));`

https://jsfiddle.net/p58189f1/